# Error in creating java project using netbeans 8.1

Tags: java, netbeans

I am having a problem while creating java project on `netbeans version 8.1`

 although i installed jdk and jre 7 and oracle-jdk too still not able to start java project.. but able to make cpp/php

the error i receive is attached in this image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Test edit the "netbeans.conf" file located in the "etc" directory where you installed Netbeans and change the parameter "netbeans_jdkhome".

Previous: netbeans_jdkhome="/usr"
Now: netbeans_jdkhome="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle"

Pointing to the address where java is installed, the address shown is for version 15.10 of Ubuntu. You may have a different directory name where java jvm is installed... for example, java-8-openjdk-amd64 or java-8-oracle

If it not works not reinstalls Netbeans but in box asking the path for java, usually "/usr" change where Java is installed "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle".